# swift update row error - attempting to add row... but there are 0 rows after update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to take a `UITableView` and add a nib file populated with a message into the array if there is one.  For the sake of testing I hardcoded a `String` into the array, but for some reason am getting the following code when the controller runs:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
***
```

I have also tried to insert the new cell at a different row (both 1 and 0) as I was not sure if that was what caused the error, but that did not work either.

This is the code I am using:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SendBirdSDK

class TestChat: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var messageArray = [String]()

    var messages: [SBDBaseMessage] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //put code below
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //load the channel with the two people
        SBDGroupChannel.createChannel(withUserIds: ["22077272", "22077273"], isDistinct: true, completionHandler: { (channel, error) in

            if(error != nil) {
                print("creation error!!!!")

            } else {
                //below load the sent messages
                let previousMessageQuery = channel?.createPreviousMessageListQuery()

                //since below has a hard coded value of 1 for the amount of messages being loaded, we add that to the array
                self.messageArray.append("Phlare")

                previousMessageQuery?.loadPreviousMessages(withLimit: 1, reverse: true, completionHandler: { (messages2, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        NSLog("Error: %@", error!)
                        return

                    } else {
                        //print(messages)
                        self.messages = messages2!
                        let msg = self.messages[0]

                        if msg is SBDUserMessage {
                            let userMessage = msg as! SBDUserMessage
                            let sender = userMessage.sender

                            //below is number of current user
                            if sender?.userId == "2077103974" {    //SBDMain.getCurrentUser()?.userId {
                                print(sender!.userId)
                                //populate the table view with a sent message, not received
                                let nib = UINib(nibName: "OutgoingUserMessage", bundle: nil)

                                let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
                                self.myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
                                self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                                self.myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                                self.myTableView.endUpdates()

                                print("user identified")
                            } else {
                                //populate below with the received xib

                                print("received message")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // ...
                })
            }
        })// ends channel creation
    }//end of view did load   

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! OutgoingUserMessage

        let msg = messageArray[indexPath.row]
        //below 
        //is
        //a
        //hardcoded
        //value
        cell.messageLabel.text = "Phlare"

        return cell
    }
}
```

I have deleted the functions for my tableView, but can add them if needed.  Currently the amount of rows being populated by the function is just a hard coded value of 1. Below is my `numberOfRowsInSection` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("test coiunt")
    print(messageArray.count)
    print(messageArray)
    //return messageArray.count
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: When you call `insertRows`, it will trigger `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` to be called. This must now return a value of one more than it did previously. But in your case, it is apparently not, resulting in your error message. Show us your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: See many similar issues at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+NSInternalInconsistencyException+%22attempt+to+insert+row%22 or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+%5Bswift%5D+NSInternalInconsistencyException+%22attempt+to+insert+row%22

Comment: @Rob That makes sense, but how would it be returning 0 after if the value is hard coded at 1?

Comment: Why don't you show us the `numberOfRowsInSection` method? The error suggests that `numberOfRowsInSection` must be returning zero, but you're saying it's coded to return 1. Also, even if it was hardcoded to always return 1, then `insertRows` would fail because it's expecting it to return one more value after the insert than it did before the insert.

Comment: @Rob I understand, and have added the code to my post.  I am currently making the change, but am confused by the error message, as there should not be 0 rows after the update, there should be 1, regardless of the second issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing `numberOfRowsInSection`. So are you seeing the `print` statement in your Xcode console? If it's saying that there are "zero" rows, its behaving as if your `numberOfRowsInSection` wasn't getting called at all, perhaps if the `dataSource` was `nil` or if you accidentally buried this method inside another. By confirming whether you're seeing that `print` statement, it could eliminate that possibility. Obviously, the hardcoded `return 1` will never work, but I'm trying to grok the error message.

Comment: @Rob yes the statements are printing, it's just printing an empty array for some reason.

Comment: Well, there's something strange going on, because this table view stuff is super robust. (The only other thing I might suggest is adding a check that you're on the main thread, e.g. `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))`).

Comment: I'd suggest you create a [simple example that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload it somewhere for us to take a look at. Create a blank project, eliminating that `SBDGroupChannel` stuff, but just add enough to reproduce the problem (but don't upload any of your existing code).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement `numberOfRowsInSection`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messageArray.count
}
```

Comment: I have the function, I just did not include in them in the post, as stated above, due to restrictions of code in my post

Comment: Okay, are you sure you have set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of `tableView` to your `TestChat` view controller?